# View.bounds.width returns the width of the view in the storyboard and not the device

Tags: swift, uiview

I'm trying to get the width of a UIView using the code below:

```
@IBOutlet var pickTopicContainer: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    print(pickTopicContainer.bounds.width)
        
        
        
}
```

However, it is printing out the width of the view shown in Main.storyboard rather than the view shown on the device the app is being run on.

Comment: The view isn't laid out yet. This should happen after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (careful though, this method can be called multiple times). If you don't expect your layout to change after presentation, I guess you could access the frame after `viewWillAppear `.

Comment: Are you saying that I should put the print statement in ```viewDidLayoutSubviews```?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to print the width then anything including or after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (like `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`) would be ok. Keep in mind that layout could change at any time (if you rotate your device for example, among other cases)

Comment: I tried putting it in both ```viewDidLayoutSubviews``` and ```viewWillAppear``` but the same thing is happening: it doesn't print out the correct width of the view that is being shown on the device that the app is being run on.